# How can I have two names for same contact in android?

Tags: contacts

I want to have one name for calls and other for text messages for same contact. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save one contact number with country code and other without it . it worked in my mobile

Comment: I want one name to be shown in onbox while other in call log.

Comment: @nAiN if it solved your issue, please mark the answer "accepted" (by ticking the "check-box" next to it). That way it appears as having a solution when browsing lists or running a query. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work on kitkat 4.4 :-( can you help?